# QGraphicsItem and hover event

Tags: qt, mousehover

I have reimplemented the hoverEnterEvent but for some reason it is not called :-(
My method is very simple at this point:

```
void LinteItem::hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent * event) {

    qDebug("Mouse hovered");
    QGraphicsItem::hoverEnterEvent(event);
}
```

I have set mouseTracking on the view. I'm able to place new LinteItems using mouseMove etc so I know the tracking works.

I have the following in the constructor:

```
setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable |
             QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable |
             QGraphicsItem::ItemSendsGeometryChanges);     
setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
```

Any idea why I do not receive the events?
I'm using Qt 5.5 btw

Answer (score 5):

It should work if your overriding custom `QGraphicsView` mouse event handlers call the original handlers of the base class, for example

```
void CustomGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    // do something...

    // send the event to graphics scene and items
    QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks yes. It does :-)